# Wanting to update my OLD video card for working with blender and games

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, games, blender

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 on my desktop pc. It is quite good for all my needs except gaming and blender3d due to an outdated graphics card. The issue is not the quality of the card, but its openGL version. It is limited to openGL 2.2, and the blender3D and the games I want to play (Team Fortress 2) need openGL 3.
As such I'm thinking of update my graphics card, not something high end, to support super high graphics settings... so I was looking for nvidia 750 gtx (http://www.clickplus.pt/p70169), an older card, so its not only cheaper but maybe better driver support.
My main issue is... can I 'simply' pop the old card out and pop the new one in with my current hardware and linux drivers installed? If not, what should I do? What do you suggest...
Here are my specs:

```
Computer
********


Summary
-------

-Computer-
Processor       : 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory      : 8129MB (1294MB used)
Operating System        : Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
User Name       : an-big (an-big)
Date/Time       : Sáb 04 Out 2014 12:32:50 WEST
-Display-
Resolution      : 1680x1050 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : Unknown
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
-Input Devices-
 Power Button
 Power Button
 Logitech USB Receiver
 Logitech USB Receiver
 Eee PC WMI hotkeys
 HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
 HDA Intel PCH Line Out
 HDA Intel PCH Line
 HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
 HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
-Printers-
No printers found
-SCSI Disks-
ATA WDC WD10EARS-00Y
TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB

Operating System
----------------

-Version-
Kernel      : Linux 3.13.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Compiled        : #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014
C Library       : Unknown
Default C Compiler      : GNU C Compiler version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
Distribution        : Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
-Current Session-
Computer Name       : an-big
User Name       : an-big (an-big)
Home Directory      : /home/an-big
Desktop Environment     : XFCE 4
-Misc-
Uptime      : 11 minutes
Load Average        : 0,00, 0,00, 0,00

Kernel Modules
--------------

-Loaded Modules-
bnep        : Bluetooth BNEP ver 1.3
rfcomm      : Bluetooth RFCOMM ver 1.11
bluetooth       : Bluetooth Core ver 2.17
binfmt_misc
ip6t_REJECT     : Xtables: packet &quot;rejection&quot; target for IPv6
xt_hl       : Xtables: Hoplimit/TTL field match
ip6t_rt     : Xtables: IPv6 Routing Header match
nf_conntrack_ipv6
nf_defrag_ipv6
ipt_REJECT      : Xtables: packet &quot;rejection&quot; target for IPv4
xt_LOG      : Xtables: IPv4/IPv6 packet logging
xt_limit        : Xtables: rate-limit match
xt_tcpudp       : Xtables: TCP, UDP and UDP-Lite match
xt_addrtype     : Xtables: address type match
nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv4
xt_conntrack        : Xtables: connection tracking state match
ip6table_filter     : ip6tables filter table
ip6_tables      : IPv6 packet filter
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns     : NetBIOS name service broadcast connection tracking helper
nf_conntrack_broadcast
nf_nat_ftp      : ftp NAT helper
nf_nat
nf_conntrack_ftp        : ftp connection tracking helper
nf_conntrack
iptable_filter      : iptables filter table
ip_tables       : IPv4 packet filter
x_tables        : {ip,ip6,arp,eb}_tables backend module
joydev      : Joystick device interfaces
snd_hda_codec_realtek       : Realtek HD-audio codec
eeepc_wmi       : Eee PC WMI Hotkey Driver
asus_wmi        : Asus Generic WMI Driver
sparse_keymap       : Generic support for sparse keymaps
snd_hda_intel       : Intel HDA driver
snd_hda_codec       : HDA codec core
snd_hwdep       : Hardware dependent layer
snd_pcm     : Midlevel PCM code for ALSA.
snd_page_alloc      : Memory allocator for ALSA system.
snd_seq_midi        : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer MIDI synth.
snd_seq_midi_event      : MIDI byte &lt;-&gt; sequencer event coder
snd_rawmidi     : Midlevel RawMidi code for ALSA.
intel_rapl      : Driver for Intel RAPL (Running Average Power Limit)
x86_pkg_temp_thermal        : X86 PKG TEMP Thermal Driver
intel_powerclamp        : Package Level C-state Idle Injection for Intel CPUs
coretemp        : Intel Core temperature monitor
kvm
crct10dif_pclmul        : T10 DIF CRC calculation accelerated with PCLMULQDQ.
snd_seq     : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer.
crc32_pclmul
ghash_clmulni_intel     : GHASH Message Digest Algorithm, acclerated by PCLMULQDQ-NI
aesni_intel     : Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, Intel AES-NI instructions optimized
aes_x86_64      : Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, asm optimized
lrw     : LRW block cipher mode
gf128mul        : Functions for multiplying elements of GF(2^128)
glue_helper
ablk_helper
cryptd      : Software async crypto daemon
snd_seq_device      : ALSA sequencer device management
serio_raw       : Raw serio driver
snd_timer       : ALSA timer interface
lpc_ich     : LPC interface for Intel ICH
nvidia
snd     : Advanced Linux Sound Architecture driver for soundcards.
mei_me      : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
mei     : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
soundcore       : Core sound module
video       : ACPI Video Driver
mac_hid
wmi     : ACPI-WMI Mapping Driver
parport_pc      : PC-style parallel port driver
ppdev
lp
parport
hid_generic     : HID generic driver
usbhid      : USB HID core driver
hid
ahci        : AHCI SATA low-level driver
psmouse     : PS/2 mouse driver
r8169       : RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
libahci     : Common AHCI SATA low-level routines
mii     : MII hardware support library

Boots
-----

-Boots-

Languages
---------

-Available Languages-
en_AG       : English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda
en_AG.utf8      : English language locale for Antigua and Barbuda
en_AU.utf8      : English locale for Australia
en_BW.utf8      : English locale for Botswana
en_CA.utf8      : English locale for Canada
en_DK.utf8      : English locale for Denmark
en_GB.utf8      : English locale for Britain
en_HK.utf8      : English locale for Hong Kong
en_IE.utf8      : English locale for Ireland
en_IN       : English language locale for India
en_IN.utf8      : English language locale for India
en_NG       : English locale for Nigeria
en_NG.utf8      : English locale for Nigeria
en_NZ.utf8      : English locale for New Zealand
en_PH.utf8      : English language locale for Philippines
en_SG.utf8      : English language locale for Singapore
en_US.utf8      : English locale for the USA
en_ZA.utf8      : English locale for South Africa
en_ZM       : English locale for Zambia
en_ZM.utf8      : English locale for Zambia
en_ZW.utf8      : English locale for Zimbabwe
pt_BR.utf8      : Portuguese locale for Brasil
pt_PT.utf8      : Portuguese locale for Portugal

Filesystems
-----------

-Mounted File Systems-
/dev/sda6   /   14,68 % (69,3 GiB of 81,2 GiB)  
none    /sys/fs/cgroup  0,00 % (4,0 KiB of 4,0 KiB) 
udev    /dev    0,00 % (3,9 GiB of 3,9 GiB) 
tmpfs   /run    0,15 % (792,7 MiB of 793,9 MiB) 
none    /run/lock   0,00 % (5,0 MiB of 5,0 MiB) 
none    /run/shm    0,58 % (3,9 GiB of 3,9 GiB) 
none    /run/user   0,02 % (100,0 MiB of 100,0 MiB) 

Display
-------

-Display-
Resolution      : 1680x1050 pixels
Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
Version     : 1.15.1
-Monitors-
Monitor 0       : 1680x1050 pixels
-Extensions-
BIG-REQUESTS
Composite
DAMAGE
DOUBLE-BUFFER
DPMS
DRI2
DRI3
GLX
Generic Event Extension
MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
MIT-SHM
NV-CONTROL
NV-GLX
Present
RANDR
RECORD
RENDER
SECURITY
SHAPE
SYNC
X-Resource
XC-MISC
XFIXES
XFree86-DGA
XFree86-VidModeExtension
XINERAMA
XINERAMA
XInputExtension
XKEYBOARD
XTEST
XVideo
XVideo-MotionCompensation
-OpenGL-
Vendor      : Unknown
Renderer        : Unknown
Version     : Unknown
Direct Rendering        : No

Environment Variables
---------------------

-Environment Variables-
USER        : an-big
LANGUAGE        : pt:pt_BR:en
UPSTART_INSTANCE
XDG_SEAT        : seat0
TEXTDOMAIN      : im-config
SSH_AGENT_PID       : 1541
SESSION     : xubuntu
HOME        : /home/an-big
DESKTOP_SESSION     : xubuntu
XDG_SEAT_PATH       : /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
INSTANCE
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS        : unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-P3T2oNqs3Q
GLADE_MODULE_PATH       : :
MANDATORY_PATH      : /usr/share/gconf/xubuntu.mandatory.path
IM_CONFIG_PHASE     : 1
SESSIONTYPE
UPSTART_JOB     : startxfce4
LOGNAME     : an-big
DEFAULTS_PATH       : /usr/share/gconf/xubuntu.default.path
XDG_SESSION_ID      : c1
PATH        : /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
GDM_LANG        : pt_PT
SELINUX_INIT        : YES
GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH       : :
XDG_SESSION_PATH        : /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR     : /run/user/1000
XDG_MENU_PREFIX     : xfce-
LANG        : pt_PT.UTF-8
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP     : XFCE
XAUTHORITY      : /home/an-big/.Xauthority
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR        : /var/lib/lightdm-data/an-big
SSH_AUTH_SOCK       : /tmp/ssh-M0BToLBk9Ypn/agent.1540
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER      : upstart
GLADE_CATALOG_PATH      : :
SHELL       : /bin/bash
GDMSESSION      : xubuntu
UPSTART_EVENTS      : started xsession
TEXTDOMAINDIR       : /usr/share/locale/
UPSTART_SESSION     : unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1425
XDG_VTNR        : 7
PWD     : /home/an-big
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS     : /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
XDG_DATA_DIRS       : /usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/usr/share
JOB     : dbus
SESSION_MANAGER     : local/an-big:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1651,unix/an-big:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1651
DISPLAY     : :0.0

Users
-----

-Users-
root        : root
daemon      : daemon
bin     : bin
sys     : sys
sync        : sync
games       : games
man     : man
lp      : lp
mail        : mail
news        : news
uucp        : uucp
proxy       : proxy
www-data        : www-data
backup      : backup
list        : Mailing List Manager
irc     : ircd
gnats       : Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin)
nobody      : nobody
libuuid
syslog
messagebus
usbmux      : usbmux daemon
dnsmasq     : dnsmasq
avahi-autoipd       : Avahi autoip daemon
kernoops        : Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon
rtkit       : RealtimeKit
saned
whoopsie
speech-dispatcher       : Speech Dispatcher
avahi       : Avahi mDNS daemon
lightdm     : Light Display Manager
colord      : colord colour management daemon
hplip       : HPLIP system user
pulse       : PulseAudio daemon
an-big      : an-big

Devices
*******


Processor
---------

-Processors-
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1900,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz     : 1600,00MHz

Memory
------

-Memory-
Total Memory        : 8129700 kB
Free Memory     : 5804584 kB
Buffers     : 160128 kB
Cached      : 844684 kB
Cached Swap     : 0 kB
Active      : 1470100 kB
Inactive        : 558264 kB
Active(anon)        : 1024872 kB
Inactive(anon)      : 43476 kB
Active(file)        : 445228 kB
Inactive(file)      : 514788 kB
Unevictable     : 0 kB
Mlocked     : 0 kB
Virtual Memory      : 15624188 kB
Free Virtual Memory     : 15624188 kB
Dirty       : 2644 kB
Writeback       : 0 kB
AnonPages       : 1023884 kB
Mapped      : 269048 kB
Shmem       : 44524 kB
Slab        : 142388 kB
SReclaimable        : 108516 kB
SUnreclaim      : 33872 kB
KernelStack     : 3304 kB
PageTables      : 34312 kB
NFS_Unstable        : 0 kB
Bounce      : 0 kB
WritebackTmp        : 0 kB
CommitLimit     : 19689036 kB
Committed_AS        : 3100692 kB
VmallocTotal        : 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed     : 122700 kB
VmallocChunk        : 34359610876 kB
HardwareCorrupted       : 0 kB
AnonHugePages       : 198656 kB
HugePages_Total     : 0
HugePages_Free      : 0
HugePages_Rsvd      : 0
HugePages_Surp      : 0
Hugepagesize        : 2048 kB
DirectMap4k     : 156096 kB
DirectMap2M     : 8185856 kB

PCI Devices
-----------

-PCI Devices-
Host bridge     : Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
Communication controller        : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Audio device        : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
PCI bridge      : Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c4) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
USB controller      : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
ISA bridge      : Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
SATA controller     : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
SMBus       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
VGA compatible controller       : NVIDIA Corporation G71 [GeForce 7900 GT/GTO] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Ethernet controller     : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
PCI bridge      : ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])


Input Devices
-------------

-Input Devices-
 Power Button
 Power Button
 Logitech USB Receiver
 Logitech USB Receiver
 Eee PC WMI hotkeys
 HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
 HDA Intel PCH Line Out
 HDA Intel PCH Line
 HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
 HDA Intel PCH Front Mic

Storage
-------

-SCSI Disks-
ATA WDC WD10EARS-00Y
TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-222BB

DMI
---

-BIOS-
Date        : 05/08/2012
Vendor      : American Megatrends Inc. (www.ami.com)
Version     : 0610
-Board-
Name        : P8Z77-V LX
Vendor      : ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. (SEAGATE, www.seagate.com)

Resources
---------

-I/O Ports-
<tt>0000-0cf7 </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>  0000-001f </tt>       : dma1
<tt>  0020-0021 </tt>       : pic1
<tt>  0040-0043 </tt>       : timer0
<tt>  0050-0053 </tt>       : timer1
<tt>  0060-0060 </tt>       : keyboard
<tt>  0064-0064 </tt>       : keyboard
<tt>  0070-0077 </tt>       : rtc0
<tt>  0080-008f </tt>       : dma page reg
<tt>  00a0-00a1 </tt>       : pic2
<tt>  00c0-00df </tt>       : dma2
<tt>  00f0-00ff </tt>       : fpu
<tt>  0200-020f </tt>       : pnp 00:04
<tt>  0290-029f </tt>       : pnp 00:07
<tt>  03c0-03df </tt>       : vga+
<tt>  03f8-03ff </tt>       : serial
<tt>  0400-0403 </tt>       : ACPI PM1a_EVT_BLK
<tt>  0404-0405 </tt>       : ACPI PM1a_CNT_BLK
<tt>  0408-040b </tt>       : ACPI PM_TMR
<tt>  0410-0415 </tt>       : ACPI CPU throttle
<tt>  0420-042f </tt>       : ACPI GPE0_BLK
<tt>  0430-0433 </tt>       : iTCO_wdt
<tt>  0450-0450 </tt>       : ACPI PM2_CNT_BLK
<tt>  0454-0457 </tt>       : pnp 00:06
<tt>  0458-047f </tt>       : pnp 00:04
<tt>    0460-047f </tt>     : iTCO_wdt
<tt>  04d0-04d1 </tt>       : pnp 00:08
<tt>  0500-057f </tt>       : pnp 00:04
<tt>  0680-069f </tt>       : pnp 00:04
<tt>0cf8-0cff </tt>     : PCI conf1
<tt>0d00-ffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>  164e-164f </tt>       : pnp 00:04
<tt>  d000-dfff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:03
<tt>    d000-d0ff </tt>     : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
<tt>      d000-d0ff </tt>       : RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
<tt>  e000-efff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:01
<tt>    e000-e07f </tt>     : NVIDIA Corporation G71 [GeForce 7900 GT/GTO] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>  f000-f01f </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
<tt>  f020-f03f </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
<tt>    f020-f03f </tt>     : AHCI SATA low-level driver
<tt>  f040-f043 </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
<tt>    f040-f043 </tt>     : AHCI SATA low-level driver
<tt>  f050-f057 </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
<tt>    f050-f057 </tt>     : AHCI SATA low-level driver
<tt>  f060-f063 </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
<tt>    f060-f063 </tt>     : AHCI SATA low-level driver
<tt>  f070-f077 </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
<tt>    f070-f077 </tt>     : AHCI SATA low-level driver
<tt>  ffff-ffff </tt>       : pnp 00:04
<tt>    ffff-ffff </tt>     : pnp 00:04
-Memory-
<tt>00000000-00000fff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>00001000-0009d7ff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>0009d800-0009ffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>000a0000-000bffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>000c0000-000cedff </tt>     : Video ROM
<tt>000d0000-000d3fff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>000d4000-000d7fff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>000d8000-000dbfff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>000dc000-000dffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>000e0000-000fffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  000e0000-000e3fff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>  000e4000-000e7fff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>  000f0000-000fffff </tt>       : System ROM
<tt>00100000-dde4ffff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>  01000000-01733733 </tt>       : Kernel code
<tt>  01733734-01d1dfff </tt>       : Kernel data
<tt>  01e76000-01fddfff </tt>       : Kernel bss
<tt>dde50000-ddfd8fff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>ddfd9000-ddfdcfff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>ddfdd000-de5e1fff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>de5e2000-de835fff </tt>     : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
<tt>de836000-de842fff </tt>     : ACPI Tables
<tt>de843000-de861fff </tt>     : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
<tt>de862000-de866fff </tt>     : ACPI Tables
<tt>de867000-de8a9fff </tt>     : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
<tt>de8aa000-decb9fff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>decba000-deff3fff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>deff4000-deffffff </tt>     : System RAM
<tt>df000000-dfffffff </tt>     : RAM buffer
<tt>e0000000-feafffff </tt>     : PCI Bus 0000:00
<tt>  e0000000-efffffff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:01
<tt>    e0000000-efffffff </tt>     : NVIDIA Corporation G71 [GeForce 7900 GT/GTO] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>  f0000000-f00fffff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:03
<tt>    f0000000-f0003fff </tt>     : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
<tt>      f0000000-f0003fff </tt>       : RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
<tt>    f0004000-f0004fff </tt>     : Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
<tt>      f0004000-f0004fff </tt>       : RealTek RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver
<tt>  f0100000-f0100fff </tt>       : pnp 00:0b
<tt>  f5000000-f70fffff </tt>       : PCI Bus 0000:01
<tt>    f5000000-f5ffffff </tt>     : NVIDIA Corporation G71 [GeForce 7900 GT/GTO] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>    f6000000-f6ffffff </tt>     : NVIDIA Corporation G71 [GeForce 7900 GT/GTO] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>      f6000000-f6ffffff </tt>       : nvidia
<tt>    f7000000-f701ffff </tt>     : NVIDIA Corporation G71 [GeForce 7900 GT/GTO] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
<tt>  f7100000-f710ffff </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
<tt>    f7100000-f710ffff </tt>     : xhci_hcd
<tt>  f7110000-f7113fff </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
<tt>    f7110000-f7113fff </tt>     : ICH HD audio
<tt>  f7115000-f71150ff </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
<tt>  f7116000-f71167ff </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
<tt>    f7116000-f71167ff </tt>     : AHCI SATA low-level driver
<tt>  f7117000-f71173ff </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
<tt>    f7117000-f71173ff </tt>     : ehci_hcd
<tt>  f7118000-f71183ff </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
<tt>    f7118000-f71183ff </tt>     : ehci_hcd
<tt>  f711a000-f711a00f </tt>       : Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
<tt>    f711a000-f711a00f </tt>     : Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
<tt>  f8000000-fbffffff </tt>       : PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-3f]
<tt>    f8000000-fbffffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>      f8000000-fbffffff </tt>       : pnp 00:0b
<tt>fec00000-fec00fff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  fec00000-fec003ff </tt>       : IOAPIC 0
<tt>fed00000-fed03fff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  fed00000-fed003ff </tt>       : HPET 0
<tt>fed10000-fed17fff </tt>     : pnp 00:0b
<tt>fed18000-fed18fff </tt>     : pnp 00:0b
<tt>fed19000-fed19fff </tt>     : pnp 00:0b
<tt>fed1c000-fed1ffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  fed1c000-fed1ffff </tt>       : pnp 00:0b
<tt>    fed1f410-fed1f414 </tt>     : iTCO_wdt
<tt>fed20000-fed3ffff </tt>     : pnp 00:0b
<tt>fed40000-fed44fff </tt>     : pnp 00:00
<tt>fed45000-fed8ffff </tt>     : pnp 00:0b
<tt>fed90000-fed90fff </tt>     : dmar0
<tt>fee00000-fee00fff </tt>     : Local APIC
<tt>  fee00000-fee00fff </tt>       : reserved
<tt>ff000000-ffffffff </tt>     : reserved
<tt>  ff000000-ffffffff </tt>       : pnp 00:0b
<tt>100000000-21effffff </tt>       : System RAM
<tt>21f000000-21fffffff </tt>       : RAM buffer
-DMA-
<tt> 4</tt>     : cascade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed drivers for you 'old' card, remove them and revert to the default Ubuntu graphics system.  Reboot your computer to ensure that all is working properly.

Then power down the computer, open the computer case, swap out cards and boot up again.  Your 'New' card may use the proprietary drivers which can be installed after you have booted your computer again.

Comment: In terms of hardware... does my motherboard support my suggested card? Sorry but my HW knowledge is limited... I got this computer as a gift.

Comment: I honestly don't know - it appears that your hardware set is relatively new, so I would suppose that it supports most graphics cards.